# Exchange Online Rule - condition for only internal domain recipient

Tags: outlook, exchange-online

I am trying to create a rule in exchange online for categorizing mail with internal recipients only. Though, only sender or recipients inclusion is configurable in the rule set. Is there any way or workaround to archive the goal?

I am thinking if power automate can archive the goal but it seems that it can only digest the new incoming email but not the email in mailbox.